# Can I encapsulate other classes within a Django model for more readable code?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model which has *a lot* of fields to the point where simply listing them all looks pretty ugly. Some of these fields can be grouped together as they have properties in common, and I'd like to put them in a separate class or model and encapsulate that within the bigger model. As an example, is it possible to do something like this:

```
class BigModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    field2 = models.BooleanField()
    ...
    grouped_data = SmallClass()

class SmallClass():
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field2 = models.IntegerField()
```

What I hope to accomplish with this is to achieve essentially the same thing as if I had simply listed all of the fields within BigModel, but with more readable code.

Another possible way I thought of accomplishing this was making `SmallClass` into a `SmallModel` and having it contain a `OneToOneField` referencing the `BigModel`. For example:

```
class BigModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    field2 = models.BooleanField()
    ...
    grouped_data = SmallClass()

class SmallModel(models.Model):
    big_model = models.OneToOneField(BigModel)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field2 = models.IntegerField()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the first one won't work at all. And the second would work, but would be a separate table.

You could use one or more mixins:

```
class SmallClass(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field2 = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
         abstract = True


class BigModel(SmallClass, models.Model):
    ...
```